# Expression Engine CMS

Tags: content-management-system, expressionengine

I’m looking at using Expression Engine for a new site I’m developing does anyone have any experience of using EE, good or bad?

I’ve looked at some other CMS but found they are quite big and although you get everything, I like EE as it looks like you can streamline it to exactly what you want your users to use?

The main feature I need is to not be taken away from the HTML and CSS and not feel restricted on what I design or relying on plugins to achieve certain aspects of the site.

The ability to create snippets of code and include them into a main template or page is really appealing. I looked at other CMS but they seem to focus more on creating pages where I would like to make up a page from varouis custom created snippets?

I come from a asp and MS SQL background rather than a php and my SQL do you think that would cause me any problems?

Comment: Great CMS. In my experience the toughest part for newbies is wrapping their head around the template system. Once you get that you'll love it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used ExpressionEngine before and found it to be extremely easy to get your head around compared to other CMS products such as Drupal. Plus, you have a lot more freedom with your designs.

One of the best resources I found on the web, is a site called train-ee.com by Mike Boyink. This is the first tutorial I did on ExpressionEngine (when I was first learning) and he goes into great detail while keeping it extremely simple:

http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/category/building-a-small-business-site/

Hope this helps.

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Jemes,

I have been building websites on EE for a few years now and it is hands-down the most flexible and powerful system to work with. You simply can build sites faster and customize it to fit clients needs better. As a company we were so happy with it that we build our own add-on for e-commerce (BrilliantRetail).

The community (#eecms on twitter) is fantastic and there are meetups, [EECI conferences](http://eeciconf.com/) (Oct 2011), [Devotee EE addons](http://devot-ee.com/) and a responsive parent company (@ellislab)constantly improving the platform.

Tony

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few bucks to spend (48$), and if you are more of a visual learner, you might want to have a look at Ryan Ierlan's screencasts on Mijingo:

http://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/learning-expressionengine-2-complete-series/

Answer (score 0):

> I come from a asp and MS SQL background rather than a php and my SQL do you think that would >cause me any problems?

I have neither background and it didn´t caused my any problems. If you don´t want to build your own plugins you won´t need to know PHP. I can´t program PHP, but never felt the      necessity to learn it.
I started with EE 0.95 backthan and never looked for any other CMS, because I could build all my sites with EE. I like the concept of haveing a comercial product that is build upon an open source foundation (code igniter) coupled with a very active and friendly community.